# Is there a new syntax for `url_for` in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In a plugin helper, I have:

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
url_for(:only_path => true, :controller => 'people', :action => 'new')
```

Note that uses the new include syntax, that part works ok.  But I get an error:

```
undefined local variable or method `controller' for #<ActionView::Helpers::InstanceTag:0x311ddf4>
```

Is there a new way to specify this, like maybe 'controller#action' ?  what's the key?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

url_for should work as usual, see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-url_for

I checked it on my console:

```
ruby-1.9.2-head > include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
 => Object 

ruby-1.9.2-head > url_for(:only_path => true, :controller => 'admin/providers', :action 
=> 'new')

=> "/admin/providers/new"
```

Maybe the error doesn't occur in the url_for because your error messages says ActionView::Helpers::InstanceTag this sounds like you're using some kind of Tag like link_to etc. Did you think about this?

Best regards

Simon

Comment: yes, I'm in a form helper, and in an instance tag... I had to make a private method:  def controller ; @controller ; end

Comment: I don't get why ruby says you're trying to access a variable/method called controller. Because the only occurrence of the word "controller" in your snippet is a symbol.

Comment: url_for internally calls a method on a controller class.  In the case of a view plugin, it does not know what controller to call, so I had to set up a private function to set it up.